# Sharp Edge on Arc

Tags: modeling, vertices, transforms

When I'm making 1911 pistol slide, I have seem to ran into problem: on the top of the slide there's streak of lines which I assume to be sharp edges. Here:

[image: 3 to 4 streaks of line]

Here's for another angle:[image]

And this is what the vortex looks like, might be a little rough, but I'm fairly new into full modelling in Blender: [image]

I tried to solve the problem myself by connecting one of the vortex in the corner to the other corner, but it's just making the streak sharper. So that's why I'm here to ask.

[image]

Comment: Hello please share the piece with the problem: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I have edited my post. You can reload.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices) unless they are coplanar with their adjacent faces, which is not the case here, otherwise we'll see the inner triangles:

[image]

Instead use quads (or sometimes tris if it doesn't cause bad shading), if the shape is not smooth enough maybe use a cylinder with more vertices:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, moonboot! Sorry for the late reply.